# Passing an entire class as argument to a thread c++ as in c#

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, class

Coming from C# I was accustomed to create instances of a certain class and then calling threads executing a class method on that object, modifying its specific variables. Here's a c#-ish example:

```
class myclass
{
  public:
    int i = 0;
    void method ()
    {
      i++;
    }
}
// then my main
myclass obj1 = new myclass(); 
myclass obj2 = new myclass(); 
myclass obj3 = new myclass();
thread first = new thread (obj1.method);
thread second = new thread (obj2.method);
thread third = new thread (obj3.method);
```

Here i would expect i can access obj1.i, obj2.i, obj3.i and that they are = 1.
I can't seem to be able to replicate this kind of behaviour in C++, probably is something very stupid, all i found as solution is use a static method, but that defeats the purpose of my code in the first place.

Comment: I would suggest you try re-writing this without the word `new`.  C++ isn't C#

Comment: Or, if you really want to make people come out in a rash; add a delete just before it;  thus getting `delete new std::thread(thing)`   (no seriously - don't do this)

Comment: that was of course an example coming from the fact i don't know how to write this in c++, which is the point of the question, why even bother answering if you don't want to help? :(

Comment: To get the address of a non-static member function the C++ syntax is `&myclass::method`. You are never going to get correct C++ by just guessing.

Comment: @MicheleEmiliani it's not about doing `this` in C++; it's about missing some of the core language features such as how to create an object on the stack vs heap; how to not have memory leaks etc.  Lastly; I didn't answer; this is the comment section; and I made the comment to point you in the right direction on how to improve.

Comment: So can i call my method with "&myclass::method", but can i do it on a specific instance of "myclass" and pass it to a thread?

Comment: @UKMonkey thanks for advices man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main should look more like this

```
myclass obj1;
myclass obj2;
myclass obj3;
thread first(&myclass::method, obj1);
thread second(&myclass::method, obj2);
thread third(&myclass::method, obj3);
```

No need to heap allocate anything with `new`.
To start a thread with a member function, you pass a pointer to the function and the object to invoke the member function on.

We also need to make sure we join the threads after.

```
first.join();
second.join();
third.join();
```

**Edit**

std::thread takes arguments by value by default, this means in the above code it will make copies of our objects and run the member functions on the copies.

If we want to make the member function run on the actual object we passed in we need to make use of a `std::reference_wrapper` like so.

```
thread first(&myclass::method, std::ref(obj1));
```

A bit tired, oversight from my part. But now updated.

Comment: @MicheleEmiliani I missed an important detail, please see the edit.

Comment: I already did some working programs with threads in C++ and i included #include <thread> nonetheless building gives me this error:

/tmp/cc6radFB.o: In function `std::thread::thread<void (myclass::*)(), std::reference_wrapper<myclass> >(void (myclass::*&&)(), std::reference_wrapper<myclass>&&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IM7myclassFvvEJSt17reference_wrapperIS1_EEEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IM7myclassFvvEJSt17reference_wrapperIS1_EEEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x24): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Comment: @MicheleEmiliani You need to link threads when you build. On my linux machine with g++, it would be done by adding `-pthread` to the compiler options when linking/building the final binary. On Windows with Visual Studio I'm guessing it would use some other flag.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code do what you want:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class myclass {
  public:
    myclass(int _i) {
      this->i = _i;
    }
    int i = 0;
    void method () {
      i++;
      cout << "Method " << i << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
  myclass obj1(1);
  myclass obj2(2);
  myclass obj3(3);

  thread t1(&myclass::method, obj1);
  thread t2(&myclass::method, obj2);
  thread t3(&myclass::method, obj3);

  //Wait for finish all threads 
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();
  return 0;
}
```